# populate List<myClass> lst from Entity Model using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I can do var lst = from p in myEntity.tblx --- no problem

instead I want to do something like

```
List<myClass> lst = from p in myEntity.tblx
```

where myClass has all the same fields as tblx

I have tried

```
List<myClass> lst = new List<myClass>();
lst = (from p in myEntity.tblx).ToList();
```

but that did not work.

say myClass looks like this

```
class myClass
{ 
    int mainID {get; set;}
    string fName {get; set;}
    string lName {get; set;}
}
```

how can I populate

```
List<myClass> lst from myEntity.tblx
```

using Linq?

Comment: Please be more specific when you say it does not work. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [projection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) part

Use

```
lst = (from p in myEntity.tblx select new myClass()){ mainID = p.mainID,  fName = p.fname, lName = p.lName}.ToList();
```

or

```
lst = myEntity.tblx.select( p => new myClass() { mainID = p.mainID,  fName = p.fname, lName = p.lName}).ToList();
```

Comment: I actually tried both of these suggestions, and even after I made my class public and the fields public -- these particular methods did not work -- lst = myEntity.tblx.select(x => x).ToList(); -- the app would not compile. error msg : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<myApp.tblx>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<myApp.myClass>'    -----  do I need to implement IEnumerable or something to myClass?  how could I get this method to work?

Comment: Yes, off course you can project to class as required

Comment: I stand corrected -- I didn't copy the whole line of code.  yes that works also.  sorry bout that.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try like below:

```
List<myClass> lst = (from p in myEntity.tblx
                select new myClass()
                {
                    mainID = p.mainID,
                    fName = p.fname,
                    lName = p.lName 
                }).ToList();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually tried something like this -- but when it didn't work I lost confidence in myself.  The actual fix was that my class and the fields needed to be declared as public.  When I added public to the class and the fields then this method worked.